# Google spreadsheet script for insert new row based on value of cell

Tags: google-sheets

[Spreadsheet data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLn2h.png)

```
function myFunction()
 { 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Active Listeners');
 sh.insertRowBefore(15551)
 }
```

As i have large range of rows that could be work on. If the value of the range matches with "Apr 9" then insert row before to that. Could anyone help me to get that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'for loop' to cycle through your rows from the bottom would almost do the trick. The loop inserts a row after each row specified by i. Keep in mind you'll need a different solution if your Apr 9 column is formatted as a date.  This works for plain text only.  You can select the column and change to plain text with "Format > Number > Plain Text" on the menu.

```
function myFunction() { 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Active Listeners');
//var shlen = sh.getDataRange().getLastRow(); //returns integer last row
var shlen = Browser.inputBox("Enter Last Row of Preferred Range", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
 var ecell = sh.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
```

You may need a different dataRange (below), I've just grabbed the parameters of data in your whole sheet (above), then grabbed a range specified in A1 notation of "A1:B[number reference of bottom row]"  The modification may be that you need "B1:C" + [shlen] or whichever other range.

```
  if (shlen >= 1) {
var dataRange = sh.getRange("A1:A" + shlen).getValues();
for (var i = shlen; i > 0; i--) {
  var row = dataRange[i-1];

  if (row[0] == "Apr 9") {
     sh.insertRowAfter(i-1)
  }
}}

}
```

Someone more knowledgeable than me can pitch in if they have a better answer, but my only solution (which should be ok if it's a one-of) would be to just repeat the script a few times, starting at the row of your choice each time. Select cell A1 and then press "control (or command) + down arrow".  It will take you to the first gap, which should be where the previous script ended. Remember the row number you're up to and plug that in the input box when you run the script again. Might take a few iterations but you'll get there.

If this process is going to be done repeatedly then best of luck in finding a solution :)

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the help. I encountered the problem here, it is inserting  some rows above Apr 9 and for some it is inserting rows after Apr 9 or inserting rows after or before of other values which are not matching with Apr 9. Please check this document [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YL_zaEf6Dooc-AiCQOdOpsf2VftoRf7NEJXxa4gZhS8/edit#gid=1044522577)

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the improved code. It is working but as the range is too large. It is stopping in the middle saying exceeded maximum time for execution. How to overcome that? Could you please check that as well

Comment: Hmm, I have some changed the code in my answer as a placeholder until I can think of something better.  I ran it and got through 4456 rows before timing out.  I'm doing some research into how to increase the speed, possibly by adding multiple rows at once or something like this.  I'll get back to you

Comment: Updated again - no luck finding a better solution than my most recent answer :(

Comment: Thanks David, it is working in about 2-3 iterations. That's okay. Thanks for the help.